# python and python2.7 runs different python instances

Tags: python, python-2.7, centos, python-2.x

This is the output when I write `whereis python2.7`

`python2.7: /usr/local/bin/python2.7 /usr/local/lib/python2.7 /opt/python2.7.1/bin/python2.7`

Version of python under `/usr/local/` is python2.7.2 and version of python under `/opt/python/2.7.1` is python2.7.1 as you see.

When I write `python` it runs `python2.7.1` because I changed the bash_profile. But When I write `python2.7` it runs `python2.7.2`.

I would like totally remove the `python2.7.2` which is under the `/usr/local/` and use the binary under `/opt/python2.7.1`.

How can I solve this problem?

Note: It is a CentOS5 server and python2.4 is already installed as you consider.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

your PATH is mixed up, do the following:

```
export PATH=/opt/python2.7.1/bin:$PATH
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/opt/python2.7.1/lib:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH
```

Comment: Should I do it on my .bash_profile also? or just doing once will be okay?

Comment: You should add it to your .bash_profile. Doing it once will work for your current session only.

Comment: PATH=$PATH:$HOME/bin

#export PATH

alias python='/opt/python2.7.1/bin/python'
alias python2.7.='/opt/python2.7.1/bin/python'
alias python2.7.1='/opt/python2.7.1/bin/python'
export PATH=$PATH:/opt/python2.7.1/bin
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/opt/python2.7.1/lib:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH

Comment: Sorry for structure of my comment above but although I added it still runs python2.7.2 when I wrote python2.7

Comment: remove your aliases. and your python `PATH` export is wrong. You add `/opt/python2.7.1/bin` before `$PATH`

Comment: that worked great.Could you look at this question also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12724050/easy-install-conflict-for-python2-4-and-python2-7 . Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

You could simply try using an alias in ~/.bash_aliases so that you always refer to the python you want inside your terminal and user instance. I would not recommend removing python2.7.2 as it might cause dependency issues

Like this

```
alias python2.7 = "/path/to/python2.7.1/"
```

Comment: alias is not enough. python has library dependencies as well.